# On Android Studio, turning background screen from white to black?

Tags: android-studio, background-color

On Android studio when I code at night, it hurts my eyes when the background is white, how do I turn it to black? I'm referring to the following...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Preferences > Editor > Color & Fonts > General > Default Text > Background
```

Will directly change the background colour.

To change to a darker theme

```
File->settings->IDE settings->Appearance->Theme
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
File -> settings -> Appearance and Behaviour -> Appearance
```

In Appearance window, change theme to `Dracula`